# Dailymotion graph API user activities

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am using the graph API of dailymotion and in particular the **/user/<id>/activities** feature.

There is no parameter to sort the list and no specification for the default sort order. Is there any guarantee that it is sorted by **created_time** (or something else) ?

The documentation :
https://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/explorer#/user/activities/list

The api explorer :
http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/obj-user.html#user-activities-connection

Thanks a lot for your input on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue. You where right, the order was already assumed to be `created_time` behind the scene. From now on, there is a new `sort` parameter that you can use to order the result set on `/activities` and `/user/<xid>/activities`. For example:

`https://api.dailymotion.com/user/<xid>/activities?fields=id,type&sort=recent`